# Python: errors with struct.pack in different uses

Tags: python, sockets, struct

It turns out that my usage of struct.pack was fine here. I was just using the wrong variables due to copy/paste errors. Remember to look out for such mistakes in your own code!

The original question is below, if you wish to see it.

---

I am needing to send two different pieces of information as payloads on UDP packets. These packets carry information on the destination of the object (that is, the destination IP Address and the destination Port Number). I have already confirmed with other methods that I am packaging the correct information. Where my problem lies is in decoding the information once I send it. Here's the info I encode, and the method used to encode them:

IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx is any number from 0 to 255)

1. IP Address is split into a list of the four numbers.
2. The list of four numbers is packed using a struct.struct('4B') where each byte is one of the list numbers.
3. on the receiving end, this is received and unpacked using an identical struct.struct("4B")
4. a string representing the IP address is reconstructed using the four unpacked values and properly placed periods.

and for the port number:

Port Number: a single integer, generally in the thousands (ie. 8000, my test value)

1. Stored using a struct.struct("H") (this is a 2-byte object which will hold the number)
2. Unpacked using an identical struct.struct("H") on the receiving end

I figure that I'm doing things right up to the encoding part, since I check the values before they are encoded and sent, and they are correct. When I get them on the other end and decode them, the values are all wrong, and I cannot figure out why. Here's an example:

Input IP and Port:

IP: 164.107.112.70
Port: 8000

Output IP and Port:

IP: 64.31.0.0
Port: 10

What might I be doing wrong here to run into these problems?

EDIT: Here's some code as requested.

```
#pack IP for transport

#split into four 1-byte values
SplitIP = IP.split('.')

#create a 4-byte struct to pack IP, and pack it in remoteIP
GB = struct.Struct("4B")

remoteIP = GB.pack(int(SplitIP[0]),int(SplitIP[1]),int(SplitIP[2]),int(SplitIP[3]))
#remoteIP is now a 4-byte string of packed IP values


#pack Port for transport

#create a 2-byte struct to pack port, and pack it in remotePort
GBC = struct.Struct("H")

remoteIP = GBC.pack(int(PORT))  #needs another byte
#remoteIP is now a 2-byte string of packed IP values


#Join the two parts together

remoteIP += str(remotePort)
```

After this, some additional elements are packed up (a 1-byte flag, a 1-byte 0/1 value for ABP (not yet implemented), and a payload (in this case, a file's size as a 4-byte value). Then they are sent via the socket send command, to another process on the same machine at a client-provided port number (in my tests, 4000 is used).

```
#get size of file from os command
filesize = bytearray(4)
#save as 4-byte string
filesize = str(os.stat(localfile).st_size)

#add flag
flag1 = bytearray(1)
flag1 = str(1)

#add zerone
if(zerone == 0):
    zerone = 1
else:
    zerone = 0

zeon = str(zerone)

#package the filesize string

filesizestr = ''.join(remoteIP)
filesizestr = filesizestr + flag1 + zeon    #now contains 4,2,1,1 byte arrays

filesizestr += filesize                     #now we have complete packet

s.sendto(filesizestr, ('127.0.0.1', int(TPORT)))
```

EDIT: A mistake was made with copy/paste, truly a common foe which must be considered at every turn of coding.

The current issue arising is that while the IP Address now sends just fine, the Port is wrong.

The sent port was 8000

The received port was @\x1f

I'm not entirely sure how to interpret that output, if anyone can help me figure what's up then I'd really appreciate it. My assumption is that I either made an encoding error or I grabbed the wrong data. As for the data, the arrangement of the string sent should be:

4 bytes for IP, 2 bytes for Port, etc.

So I grab that info with the following two lines:

```
packedIP = data[0:4]    #grab 4-byte IP data
packedPort = data[4:6]  #grab 2-byte port data
```

This is proper, yes? I am still a little confused with how Python string accessors work. The IP I got right though, so I think that I'm okay.

EDIT: Nevermind that problem before, I made more foolish errors with using the wrong variables.

Comment: unrelated: you could encode / decode an ip to be sent over a network using `socket.inet_aton() / .inet_ntoa()` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in theory the bytes on the wire should be:

```
A4 6B 70 46 1F 40
```

But what you decoded appears to be

```
40 1F 00 00 00 0A
```

It looks suspicious that the last two bytes of the first set are the first two bytes (reversed) in the second set. Could we see the code you're using? That might help identify the precise problem.

Also, are the machines little endian or big endian? When I do byte-packed structs I typically use network ordering (big endian), which means you should prefix your struct strings with an exclamation point (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

EDIT: Your problem is this line:

```
remoteIP = GBC.pack(int(PORT))  #needs another byte
```

it should be

```
remotePort = GBC.pack(int(PORT))  #needs another byte
```

Comment: I added source as you requested. I hope it is sufficient. I am not sure of the endian needs.

Comment: You have a likely copy/paste error. You're overwriting `remoteIP` when you encode the port number, instead of setting `remotePort`.

Comment: Ha! What a silly mistake! I have updated it and will report back on how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for helping me notice the goofy copy/paste errors I had made on this code.